# React Native ios app build failed with "select a development team error"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have initialized an app with react-native init something.
When I try to build it with Xcode it's throwing me this error.

`Showing Recent Messages
:-1: Signing for "organiseTests" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor. (in target 'organiseTests')`

But I have added the developer account in the **Signing** section.I'm using Xcode 10.1 and my physical device is iPhone 6

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to set the team in the test target as well as mentioned in the error message.

Even though its not required to set the team in other targets if you are not compiling them but Xcode sometimes gives error.

Comment: Where is the test target ?? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Select your project from the project navigator. In the project editor, you will see list of targets under Targets heading. Select 'organiseTest' and specify the team.

Answer (score 2):

You can show the Targets in the following way:

1. Open XCode
2. Click at the very Top Element in the Explorer
3. If Project-Tab is not shown, click the Icon to make "Project-Column" visible.

There you see all your targets. Remove unneeded Targets, or check if `Team` is choosed for each Target.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try selecting the team as none. The provisioning profile should show none required.